# How to capture data values to the power of ^ (...) in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, storage

Perhaps someone with more experience in SQL Server can be of assistance. I am in the middle of putting together the LookUp tables for a new project. For 2 different tests that a user can perform (Bacteria/Fungi) the results are currently recorded on paper as the following:

BACTERIA:
Bacteria cfu / ml

- <100
- 10^2
- 10^3
- 10^4
- 10^5
- 10^6
- 10^7

FUNGI:
Fungi (yeast & mold) cfu /ml

- <100
- 10^2
- 10^3
- 10^4
- 10^5

  What would be the best way to capture these values in SQL Server 2008 R2? In particular, Data Type and Size?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would probably be good enough:

```
CREATE TABLE AmountLookup (
  UnitsLimitExp int NULL,
  Name nvarchar(10) NULL
)

INSERT INTO AmountLookup
SELECT 2, '<100'
UNION ALL SELECT 3, '10^3'
UNION ALL SELECT 4, '10^4'
UNION ALL SELECT 5, '10^5'
UNION ALL SELECT 6, '10^6'
UNION ALL SELECT 7, '10^7'
```

This way you store the exponent, not the amount. Real value is just a GUI representation. Another thing is your lookup name, which is ugly here (10^3). However, you can store HTML code and treat it as raw HTML on your user interface, e.g. 10<sup>4</sup> is `10<sup>4</sup>`.

Comment: I think `tinyint` should be enough

Comment: Lots of people don't care about differences between int-based types, so I try to avoid it in my answers. However, you are right.

Comment: You are missing 10^2 and would use 1 for < 100

Comment: I can't agree with storing HTML code in the database - your database and presentation method should not be so coupled.

Comment: @SteveHomer: ok, it can be improved by decoupling, put HTML in separate resource file and reference the resource by a key stored in database. However, if you don't want to hardcode this, HTML will have to be stored somewhere, be it a resource file, database, xml, wherever.

Answer (score 0):

If these are value and not ranges, `INT` will work. If you start to deal with values greater than 2 billion, `BIGINT` should be used. If you need decimal digits, you can use the `DECIMAL` (`NUMERIC`) type.

Your other option, since these are discrete values, is to use a lookup table for the values, whose surrogate key id you can use in the tables that hold references to the data. That way you can represent a concept such as "<100" .

Comment: In these instances, the user will perform the test, then compare the test strip results to a chart with the above listed values and graphical representations. Would your solution still be best? (I am assuming using `String` values would be a horrible idea, storing the values like "10^5"?)

Answer (score 0):

I'd propose a `varchar(50)`:

- <100 "Clean enough"
- 10^2 "Food over due date"
- 10^3 "Mr Bean's armpits"
- 10^4 "Three day old carcass"
- 10^5 "Biochemical experiment"
- 10^6 "Maggot invasion"
- 10^7 "Bacteria overflow"